# Metadata landsat incompatibility?

Tags: landsat

I compiled the last [ledaps](https://github.com/USGS-EROS/espa-surface-reflectance) from source, but when I try to convert the MLT file to the espa xml format I get this error:

```
Error: read_lpgs_mtl : Unsupported resampling option: CC
```

It turns out that the resampling option found in these metadata files is:

```
RESAMPLING_OPTION = "CC"
```

While the [source code](https://github.com/USGS-EROS/espa-product-formatter/blob/master/src/raw_binary/format_conversion_libs/convert_lpgs_to_espa.c) is looking for the string "CUBIC_CONVOLUTION":

```
if (!strcmp (tokenptr, "CUBIC_CONVOLUTION"))
    tmp_bmeta.resample_method = ESPA_CC;
```

When did the metadata standard change? How can I make both compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone runs into the same problem. The metadata standard was changed in August 2012 as can be found in [landsat site](http://landsat.usgs.gov/Landsat_Metadata_Changes.php).

> On August 29, 2012, metadata files and filenames associated with
>   Landsat Level 1 Products changed. Modifications were made to make
>   filenames, metadata fields, and files consistent for all sensors,
>   including Landsat 8 data products.